# How to open .jar file from shell script without losing focus?

Tags: command-line, java, focus

In my script I need to open .jar file and keep focus on terminal.
I tried `java -jar maps.jar &`, but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: First of all what do you mean about "without loosing focus" specially in **shell script**? Why didn't work? Did you get any error? what is the output of `java --version`? Does `java -jar maps.jar` alone without `&` on end works? please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/583501/edit) your question and add more details. Th4nk5 :)

Comment: Also make sure your path is correct! Assume `maps.jar` is in a folder called project, located in your Documents folder, then your command would be: `java -jar Documents/projects/maps.jar`

Comment: It's `java -version`. `java --version` results in an error about an unrecognised option.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wrote not too precisely, I run my script in terminal, and during script execution I need to open .jar and keep active window on terminal. TobyLL's solution works perfectly. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `xdotool`, but it's not particularly elegant.  As a one-off task, make sure that `xdotool` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then you can launch your jar as follows:

```
TERM_HANDLE=`xdotool getwindowfocus`; java -jar maps.jar & sleep 5; xdotool windowactivate $TERM_HANDLE
```

The `xwindow getwindowfocus` gets the current window handle and stores it in the TERM_HANDLE variable.  Then your `java -jar maps.jar &` is launched.  You'll then need a sleep until this command has started (pick an appropriate value that works for you), before using the `xdotool windowactivate` to bring the terminal back to the front.